# windows 7 blue screen (bugcode usb driver)

Tags: windows-7

i have been getting Bugcode_usb_driver blue screen for more than 4 months, now i am in college and it doesn't help me doing my work.

can someone help me please!!

here is the details of the problem:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    2108

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   fe
  BCP1: 0000000000000008
  BCP2: 0000000000000006
  BCP3: 0000000000000005
  BCP4: FFFFFA8005602000
  OS Version:   6_1_7600
  Service Pack: 0_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\103012-86096-01.dmp
  C:\Users\DocentKowalik\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-171772-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/verify-the-integrity-of-windows-vista-system-files/ This will work on win7 as well as vista.

Comment: ask a local technical friend who can physically inspect the machine.

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/crashes-debugging/261081-various-bsod-bcp1-0000000000000008-a.html